# [admin-on-rest]-"Warning" when create <SimpleForm/> with ImageInput

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I create SimpleForm with ImageInput.

I followed the instructions in the document:
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#imageinput
This is my code:

```
export const PostCreate = (props) => (
    <Create actions={<PostCreateEditActions/>} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm toolbar={<PostCreateEditToolbar/>} defaultValue={postCreateDefaultValue}>        
            <ImageInput source="pictures" label="画像" accept="image/*" >
                <ImageField source="src"/>
            </ImageInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

But when the console logs error:

```
bundle.js:4903 Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

Check the render method of TextField.
```

Could you explain the cause of the error?

Comment: Please upload your `TextField` component

Comment: It not have TextField,
My page only have a <ImageInput/>, as in the attached code

Comment: If you didn't, then the error would not say `Check the render method of TextField`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I believe @Hoa is looking for help with the `admin-on-rest` framework and the referenced duplicate question above is not especially helpful. I'm having a similar issue; `TextField` is a component provided by this framework, so editing it is not a great solution.

Comment: oh, @quicklikerabbit, thank you for you comment. Actually!
This is a problem when running webpack in developer mode, (webpack -d),
When you run in prodcuction mode, this error will be gone (webpack -p).